# SharePoint 2013 Auto populate person column in list with creator name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, column

I have a custom list which contains several columns. I want to add a column to the list which I would like to be a "name/person" field which is mapped to registered users on SharePoint (or AD).

But I want this field/column to be automatically populated with the creator (users-) name, when the user clicks "Add new item" to the list.

How do one achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new people and group column `"name/person"` and set the defaul value to `[ME]`. Then if you press create new item the form will show the person who creates in that field automatically. And if he needs, he could change this field to different one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the steps you can use to auto populate user name into the form
Open any test list->customize InfoPath->click on people picker you want to auto populate-> right side->Fields panel-> (down) click on Show Advanced view->
[image]

Click on (+) for expansion->First right click on AccountId properties->click on fx->click on insert function->User->username->click ok button->ok->ok
[image]

Now come back infopath design path again on right hand side Fields-> now right click on AccountType->right click on properties->in value text box->just type-user->click ok button.

[image]

Publish to SharePoint->it will autocomplete the user into the form in SharePoint.

For new item-> after submitting the form-> you can see the user with status

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create new field. Use out of the box Created By field for that.

If you don't want to use that then create a new User field and set Default Value as **[ME]**

Comment: Thank you. The thing is that it does not have to be equal to the user creating the new list item. Also the column/field is of the lookup type "person or group". And for this type of column/field I see no "Default Value" options.

Comment: When adding **[ME]** for a single text column, what is displayed seems to be a SharePoint path and the users name is not looking nicely formatted.

Comment: it should be not single text column, but people picker column with default value [me]

Comment: In SharePoint 2013, there is no option for a default value in people-picker fields.  You have to use alternate methods, such as javascript, an event handler, or a workflow.